# Programação embarcada

Tags: debate

Eu estudo engenharia elétrica e pretendo me especializar em programação embarcada.
Hoje eu crio aplicações android, programo processadores embarcados, crio banco de dados e crio programinhas que me aparecem, 
comecei a usar o SO-pt a uns 9-10 dias, e me ajudou bastante, tenho entrado todos os dias desde então.

percebi que o SO-pt não engloba uma parte voltada para programação embarcada, 
seria bem interessante implementar essa parte, ja que a programação embarcada requer muitos mais detalhes, que coisas bobas fazem não funcionar.

acredito que muito mais pessoas passariam a utilizar o SO-pt.

mas essa modificação teria que ser bem pensada para não bagunçar tudo.

Answer (score 4):

Não consegui entender muito como o SOpt não está englobando programação embarcada, nem como poderia mudar para fazê-lo.

Pode ser que faltem usuários especializados no assunto, mas este é um problema completamente diferente.

Creio que não há problema algum em postar perguntas sobre o assunto, desde que seja sobre desenvolvimento de programas e não sobre *hardware*.

--

**Atualização**

Já temos suporte para códigos Assembly. Exemplo:

```
<!-- language: lang-apollo -->  

    MOV AL, 1h        ; Load AL with immediate value 1
    MOV CL, 2h        ; Load CL with immediate value 2
    MOV DL, 3h        ; Load DL with immediate value 3
```

Quanto às tags, você pode solicitar a criação de uma tag específica aqui no meta ou então ela será criada à medida que novas perguntas forem feitas e surgir a necessidade. Não creio que seja o caso de começar a criar tags vazias para o caso de um dia usá-las.

Comment: teria que ter tipo de processador(talvez em tags)
e suporte para códigos assembly/c juntos.
acho que da para fazer com tags, a grande coisa é trazer os desenvolvedores embarcado para cá, divulgar mesmo, e levar isso na descrição.

Comment: @Joannis Fiz uma atualização na resposta. Veja se corresponde ao que você perguntou. ;)

Comment: Sim @Joannis você pode trazer programadores com este expertise para o site. Todos se beneficiarão.

Comment: quando eu for fazer a programação embarcada colocarei minhas duvidas aqui, e por aparecer no google talvez traga mais programadores, 
por mais que elas talvez não sejam respondidas.

Comment: @Joannis Fique à vontade. Eu não sei praticamente nada de programação embarcada, a não ser o que vi na faculdade. Seria um aprendizado interessante. Abraço.